# What are the equivalent compilation options for gfort given the ifort compilation?

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to compile a code using gfortran instead of ifortran. The gfortran code runs much much slower than the ifortran code. It does not even use all threads from my computer. I have 40 cores and 80 threads. ifort uses all of them.I think it has to do with the ifort flag `/Qm64` but can't be sure (using the /Qm32 flag on ifort is slower and does not use all the threads on openmp - not sure why).

This is the way that visual studio seems to be compiling my code:

```
Compiling with Intel® Fortran Compiler Classic 2021.4.0 [Intel(R) 64]...
ifort /nologo /O2 /Qopenmp /module:"x64\Release\\" /object:"x64\Release\\" /Fd"x64\Release\vc160.pdb" /libs:dll /threads /c /Qlocation,link,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64" /Qm64 "D:\test\main1.f90"
Linking...
Link /OUT:"x64\Release\DebtDuration.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"x64\Release\DebtDuration.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /STACK:999999999 /IMPLIB:"D:\test\x64\Release\DebtDuration.lib" -qm64 "x64\Release\splint.obj" "x64\Release\linspace.obj" "x64\Release\random_normal.obj" "x64\Release\spline.obj" "x64\Release\rouwenhorst.obj" "x64\Release\bspline_sub_module.obj" "x64\Release\main1.obj"
Embedding manifest...
```

Here's how I was trying to compile in gfortran:

```
gfortran -c -O2 -m64 bspline_sub_module.f90 
gfortran -w -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-0 -m64 -O2 -fopenmp main1.f90 random_normal.f90 linspace.f90 bspline_sub_module.o rouwenhorst.f90 spline.f90 splint.f90
gfortran -fopenmp main1.o random_normal.o linspace.o bspline_sub_module.o rouwenhorst.o spline.o splint.o
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a video with what I mean in terms of differences in thread/core usage:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sc2ebrzckz9y0m1/Video_fortran.mp4?dl=0

If I compile my ifort code with \qm32 flag it gets similar performance to the gfortran.

Comment: What is your code actually doing? We can't say why one compiler's code is slower without seeing the source code (and quite possibly not even with the code). How do you set the parallel environment? What kind of hardware?

Comment: Vladimir, those are fair questions. The code is a very long code, certainly not suitable for here (and hard to create a minimal working example that replicates it). I am still one step behind trying to understand whether the code itself is driving the cause. For now I am just thinking about compilation options (since there is a massive difference in ifort between qm32 vs qm64 and that is what drives the differences in number of threads used ... I am guessing I am doing something wrong on gfort compilation). Hardware: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248 CPU @ 2.50GHz   2.49 GHz  (2 processors)

Comment: It does not make much sense to use m32 on a 64-bit CPU.

Comment: How are you setting affinity options? Without that the OS is under no obligation to have any correspondence between threads and cores.

Comment: The O2 flag did not change anything. @VictorEijkhout, I am not sure what you mean with regards the affinity options. But even doing call omp_set_num_threads(80) on gfort did not help (since it keeps using only 40 threads), and being 3 times slower than ifort.

Comment: environment variables: `OMP_PROC_BIND=true` and `OMP_PLACES=cores`

Comment: Btw, do not try 80 threads if you have 40 cores. Hyperthreads hardly ever help. Ask omp how many procs it thinks there are: `omp_get_nprocs`. Maybe it thinks there are only 40. Oh, and how can you tell it's only using 40 threads? Threads are a software construct: OMP will happily create a 100 threads on 2 cores. So how did you draw that conclusion?

Comment: I agree with Victor. The affinity issues with 2 processors was the reason I asked for the hardware before going to sleep. But I also find it very unlikely that adding `-O2` would not change anything. You should certainly post the actual performance measurements you do and the actual new compilation commands.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout and Vladimir thank you both for your comments. I have updated the compile instructions with the O2 flag, and I have included a video that shows the performance of both codes. The first iteration of the ifort loop runs in 19.9 seconds with 100% CPU usage, the first iteration of the gfort loop runs in 38.8 seconds (almost double) with 50% CPU usage. 
VictorEijkhout sorry for being dumb, where/how do I set those environment variables?

Comment: Environment variables: on the commandline. Unless you're on Windows. Then you're on your own. Google is your friend.

Comment: Btw, 50% cpu usage only means that half your cores are unused. The busy 20 cores could be hosting 5000 threads, with the OS swapping them very efficiently. There is no way you can tell. The only thing you see is the hardware. And then I'm guessing that the OS for whatever reason is not filling all cores. `OMP_PROC_BIND=true` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not enabling any compiler optimizations for gfortran. It is pointless to reason about performance without them. Try at least `-O2` or `-O3`. They are not necesarily equivalent for.both compilers, but similar. There are many other optimizations flags available in the manual. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html